# Render Active Storage being Deleted every time I repush

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render

Ok, so I got my app on Render and everything works fine... Until I push an update, at which point all the pictures go bye bye. Is this an effect of the free tier, or is there something I'm doing wrong? This is the last thing I have to solve, so any input would be appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: `The default filesystem for services running on Render is ephemeral` which means that , just like Heroku, if you upload images, on the next push they go away (I think after a period of time as well). The docs at that link specifically state, `Application data isn’t persisted across deploys and restarts`. The likely solution is hosting files in something like S3, or whatever.  I found this information here: https://render.com/docs/disks

Comment: What's the cheapest of those if I'm a student at the moment